# pfsense in virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, pfsense

I'm new to pfSense and VirtualBox, I have a PC running Ubuntu, in Ubuntu I run a VirtualBox host. pfSense is installed as a virtual machine. I have two network adapters, one connected to my modem(WAN), one connected to a switch (LAN). I bridged the adapters to my virtual machine. Everything works, I was able to connect to the Internet, other computers in LAN is able to obtain IP addresses from pfSense, working perfectly fine. 
**The only issue here is I don't know how I would connect my virtual machine host into the same network as other PC in LAN.**

**Edit:**
to make it clear, here is a graph to my network

[image: my network]

How should I configure interfaces enp3s0 to get an IP address from the pfSense's DHCP?

Comment: You failed to describe your connection scheme. Start from a scratch.

Comment: Your host, the physical machine running Ubuntu and Vbox must have an IP address, so what's the question here?

Comment: the physical machine has no IP address

Comment: Why don't you just give it a static address?

Comment: i got it working by setting enp3s0 on DHCP, and plugged into switch. Is there a way to set this up(host client communication) without needing external network(without needing to plug into switch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you got it working with DCPH, meaning your IP settings is being served from your local DHCP server in pfsense.

My understanding is that you want to assign *a static IP address* to your enp3s0 network device.

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

At the bottom of this file add the following lines (adapt to suit your configuration):

```
iface enp0s3 inet static
      address 192.168.1.50
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

Enable the new configuration by restarting the networking service.

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

This way your Virtual Machine Host will be assigned static IP address 192.168.1.50, and all its' outgoing internet traffic will be routed via your Pfsense router. In addition, all DNS queries will directed to your PfSense (assuming this is your local DNS, else just add OpenDNS addresses 208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220 instead).

Comment: yeah i got this figured out already, problem is, i have to plug into the switch to get a gigabits connection, is there a way to do this without needing to plug into switch? i want a 10gbs connection btween host and guest

Comment: RIght now you are communicating on sub-net 192.168.1.0 which is only reachable if your enp0s3 is in active link state, i e when you are connected to the switch. Another approach would be to define a separate sub-net to communicate between host and vPfsense. That would evolve setting up a bridge network device on your host for the new sub-net, and defining a new em interface on your vPfsense. That would provide IP connectivity regardless if the host is connected to the external switch, or not. Since I don't run this type of virtual set-up I am not able to provide any configuration details.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same, trying to set up a host-only interface dedicated to do the host <-> guest communication, and tried to bridge the two interfaces on virtual pfsense so they are all on the 192.168.1.0 subnet, can't get it working.

Comment: I think you are supposed to assign the IP address to the bridge device rather than to one of the bridge members.